# http POST method not working with iOS

Tags: php, html, ios, forms, post

Ok, so I have researched obsessively to resolve this problem. I have a PHP script which auto-generates an approval email with the mail() function. I generate an e-mail that creates the form shown below which uses the POST method for two buttons, approve and deny. The code works on everything but iOS devices. On iOS, the script fails because the PHP script that is tied to the "Action" attribute doesn't recognize the Request Method as POST when it is done through an iOS device. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<form method="post" id="Approve" action="https://www.blahblahblah.com/Approval.php">
  <input required for="submit" type="hidden" name="Check" value="12"/>
  <input required for="submit" type="hidden" name="Approval" value="1" />
  <input required type="submit" value="Im cool with this">
</form>

<form method="post" id="Deny" action="https://www.blahblahblah.com/Approval.php">
  <input required for="submit" type="hidden" name="Check" value="12" />
  <input required for="submit" type="hidden" name="Approval" value="0" />
  <input required type="submit" value="Im not cool with this">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean the issue occurs on Safari for iOS?  Or within an iOS app you're developing?

Comment: My apologies, when the user clicks the button on an iOS device, let it be through their Apple mail client or through like Gmail, it does not work.

Comment: I am developing an Android app, but the mail can go to any device.